# How to delete D drawn lines? (Erase Annotation)

Tags: interface

[image]
So rather per accident, I learned that you can draw blue lines using D. But now I want to get rid of them. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to erase the annoation, type <kbd>D</kbd> + right click, or enable the annotation tool and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click:

[image]